# Leaflet, clicking zoom control removes paging-top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I am trying to put a bootstrap nav bar on top of my leaflet map.  When I click on the zoom control buttons my nav bar disappears and I have no idea why.

Is this a leaflet bug?

```
  <body>
<header class="navbar navbar-static-top bs-docs-nav" id="top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">Test Leaflet Navbar</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse">
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

    <div style="height: 100%">
          <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js" data-require="leaflet@0.7.3" data-semver="0.7.3"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Here is a plunk showing the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/C8O6bB?p=preview

Notice that when you first load the page all looks ok.  But clicking on the zoom control buttons makes the navbar disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your navbar doesn't disappear, the page scrolls to the top of your map. You can scroll up. There's your navbar :) What you want to do here is give your body 100% height minus the height of your navbar and remove the margin:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 51px); /* minus navbar incl. border */
}

html, #map {
    height: 100%;
}

header.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0; /* remove bottom margin */ 
}
```

Here's an updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zmXyDj?p=preview